# Create password dialog window

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, window

How do i put up a password dialog window before starting up the main dialog window?

Comment: Do you mean open a windows authentication dialog or create a custom password dialog?

Comment: A password dialog window to grant access to the application.

Comment: Are you hard coding the dialog or using a resource file?

Comment: I'd be using both password and main dialog from a resource file but I could create a hard coded window as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create the dialog as you would create any other dialog.

Perhaps the root of your question is that you aren't sure how to create the `EDIT` control that shows a password. The trick is to create it with the [`ES_PASSWORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775464%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#ES_PASSWORD) style so that the text the user enters is hidden when they type.

You'll probably not want to store the password in your executable in plain text format.

Your question doesn't give us much to go on. It would be better if you stated what your problem is, where you are stuck, what you don't understand, etc.

Comment: Normally, I'd create a child window without redefining the message loop. But when you need your own window before starting main window, I got confused thinking that would I really need two message loops for two separate modeless dialogs?

Comment: @user2133 Surely the password dialog is a modal dialog and so runs its own message loop? If its modeless that's no problem, both modeless windows will run quite happily out of the main app's message loop.